# jQuery.eCalendar() - displaying wrong date

Tags: jquery

I am having problem displaying event on 31st.

All the events on 31st will automatically changed to 1st of that month. Is there anyway to fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
$('#calendar').eCalendar({
  weekDays: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
  months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
  textArrows: {
    previous: '<',
    next: '>'
  },
  eventTitle: 'Events',
  url: '',
  events: [{
    title: 'Event 1',
    description: 'Description 1',
    datetime: new Date(2019, 8, 31, 17)
  }, {
    title: 'Event 2',
    description: 'Description 2',
    datetime: new Date(2019, 9, 14, 16)
  }, {
    title: 'Event 3',
    description: 'jQueryScript.Net',
    datetime: new Date(2019, 9, 10, 16)
  }, {
    title: 'Event 3',
    description: 'jQueryScript.Net',
    datetime: new Date(2019, 8, 23, 16)
  }]
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03y82xak/)

Comment: Month argument starts from 0-11. You are putting 8, it means september. September has 30 days, that's why 31st moving to 1 Oct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Month argument starts from 0-11. Putting 8 means September. September has 30 days, that's why 31st moving to 1 Oct.

Update 1: 
I am not sure if ecalendar provide option for sorting but we can sort events array using sort method.

```
[<events array>].sort((a, b) => a.datetime < b.datetime ? -1 : 1)

$('#calendar').eCalendar({
  weekDays: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
  months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
  textArrows: {
    previous: '<',
    next: '>'
  },
  eventTitle: 'Events',
  url: '',
  events: [{
    title: 'Event 1',
    description: 'Description 1',
    datetime: new Date(2019, 7, 31, 17)
  }, {
    title: 'Event 2',
    description: 'Description 2',
    datetime: new Date(2019, 8, 14, 16)
  }, {
    title: 'Event 3',
    description: 'jQueryScript.Net',
    datetime: new Date(2019, 8, 10, 16)
  }, {
    title: 'Event 4',
    description: 'jQueryScript.Net',
    datetime: new Date(2019, 7, 23, 16)
  }].sort((a, b) => a.datetime < b.datetime ? -1 : 1)
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! May I know is it possible to sort events by date on the listing? Appreciate if you can help! :)